# Deep Routing not working as expected ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my code for routing and as I checked on internet, using html5Mode with requireBase should have fixed this problem.
When I directly try to access **localhost/index**, then it is saying **Cannot GET /login**

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // Setting login page as default location for the App
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

    $stateProvider.state('root', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
            "temp_app": {
                templateUrl: 'app.tpl.html'
            }
        }
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });
});
```

Comment: `requireBase: false` isn't the right solution. You have an issue with express not serving your app on other URLs. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a web server issue, and while you didn't specify which tech, I peeked at another question of your tagged with IIS, so if you are indeed using IIS, you need to include some `<rewrite>` rules in your `Web.config`. `requireBase: false` is also not the right approach, we instead **need** a base. Observe the following example...

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
[...]
```

---

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true
    });
[...]
```

---

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*"/>
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If my hunch is wrong, and you are not using IIS, see rewrite solutions for common webservers including (along with IIS): **Apache**, **Nginx**, and **Express** - [How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Also, see the [$location docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for more information, along with [Error: $location:nobase
$location in HTML5 mode requires a tag to be present!](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase) for some deeper insight on to why we need to set our apps up this way

Comment: I am currently using Grunt locally on my machine. Any solution for that??